# Python Pillow - broken data stream

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

Pillow looks to be the solution to a lot of my problems, but I can't get it to work correctly.  I think there might be something that I'm missing but I can't find any solutions that work.

```
from PIL import Image

img = Image.open("base64 (1).png")

print(img.size)
print(img.format)
img.show()
```

I have this set up to load an image, print its size and format, and then show the image.  When I run the code, I get this:

```
(1920, 1080)
PNG
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/##########/PycharmProjects/weatherCanvas/imageTest.py", line 7, in <module>
    img.show()
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 1736, in show
    _show(self, title=title, command=command)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 2449, in _show
    _showxv(image, **options)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 2454, in _showxv
    ImageShow.show(image, title, **options)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageShow.py", line 51, in show
    if viewer.show(image, title=title, **options):
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageShow.py", line 75, in show
    image = image.convert(base)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 844, in convert
    self.load()
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageFile.py", line 250, in load
    raise_ioerror(e)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageFile.py", line 59, in raise_ioerror
    raise IOError(message + " when reading image file")
IOError: broken data stream when reading image file
```

The same thing happens if I replace `img.show()` with saving it.  I know that PIL and Pillow save a temporary file in order to do the `show()` method, so I think the problem is somewhere in that.

Is there something I'm missing here?